# Please read Martha's story and forgive me if I interrupt your schedule. Should it be INTERRUPTED? Thank you.

Tags: grammar

English is my second language.  I have a problem.  Is this statement correct:  Please read Martha's story and forgive me if I interrupt your schedule.  Should it be INTERRUPTED?  Thank you.

Comment: It's correct as it is, not "interruped." Read: "... if I happen to be interrupting ...." HTH.

Comment: "Forgive me if I **have interrupted** your schedule" would also be correct.

Comment: It depends on the context (and what the speaker means).

Answer (score 1):

I would say 'Please read Martha's story and forgive me if **it interrupts** your schedule', which means that you are apologizing for this **reading** of the story that will potentially interrupt someone's ***schedule***

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear if the second half of your sentence means:

- forgive me if reading Martha's story interrupts your schedule

or

- forgive me if I interrupted your schedule when I asked you just now.

In the first case 'interrupt' is technically correct, though most people would say 'forgive me if it interrupts your schedule' (i.e. the reading). In the second case either 'interrupt' or 'interrupted' is reasonable, since you could think of the interruption as being now or (a very small time) in the past. A more normal phraseology for the second case is: "Forgive me if I interrupt your schedule, but please read Martha's story".